# What is the best practice taking a snapshot VMWare

Tags: windows, snapshot

Is there a difference between taking a snapshot of a VMWare Windows server with it powered on and it being powered down.  I have always took a snapshot for quick changes and reverting back to the previous with the server powered on.  I would make sure not to "Snapshot the virtual machine's memory" and not to "Quiesce guest file system".

Is one way any better to perform for stability and safety net of the snapshot?

Comment: Just be sure to **Do not use snapshots as backups** Thus be sure to have a working backup too in case your snapshot got corrupted data in it.

Answer (score 4):

> Is one way any better to perform for stability and safety net of the
>   snapshot?

If you require a guaranteed clean filesystem, you must either shut down the OS or ensure that the filesystem is mounted read-only. Anything else, even with "Quiesce..." enabled, you run the possibility of file corruption and/or other inconsistencies in the snapshot.